# JS Filter and Map

Tags: node.js, json

I am trying to take a JSON response, filter it to find a specific matching group and if it matches, return a single key value.

My current attempt is:

```
let res = item.filter(it => it.groups.includes('unknown') && it.iccid);
    console.log(res.it.iccid)
```

But if my response has five items that are apart of the same group, how to I cycle through to output each?

I'd like to use item.map((it) => { return it['itemhere'] but unsure how to filter to get matching groups only...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm following you correctly, you want to figure out if the item's `group` array contains the term `unknown` and if so, to return the `iccid` of the item.

One way to do it would be:

```js
let items = [{ ...your array of objects... }]

items = items.filter(item => {
  const unknown = item.groups.filter(i => i.includes('unknown'))
  if (unknown.length && item.iccid) { return item }
})

items.forEach(item => console.log(item))
```